# React Passing Boolean value to component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass a Boolean value to my component so it can show an image depending on if it is true or false but I am not very sure how to proceed here.

#### Here is the code:

Passing *Boolean* value to component:

```
<SomeComponent showImage={false}/>
```

Trying to use it on component:

```
const TheImage = showImage => (

      <div align="center">
        {showImage ? (<img src={ImageIwant} alt="The image i want" width="80%" height="80%" />) : ''}
        <p>Here is the image</p>
      </div>);
```

I am new to react an i am not sure why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your show image component from

```
const TheImage = showImage => (

  <div align="center">
    {showImage ? (<img src="https://lcsc.academyofmine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Test-Logo.svg.png" alt="The image i want" width="80%" height="80%" />) : ''}
    <p>Here is the image</p>
  </div>);
```

to

```
const TheImage = prop => (

  <div align="center">
    {prop.showImage ? (<img src="https://lcsc.academyofmine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Test-Logo.svg.png" alt="The image i want" width="80%" height="80%" />) : ''}
    <p>Here is the image</p>
  </div>);
```

Because your component will have the prop as an object so if you want to access any property which is passed you need to use `prop.yourpropertyname`

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5vqvw6)

Answer (score 5):

Add curly braces to showImage to destruct it

```
const TheImage = { showImage } => (

      <div align="center">
        {showImage ? (<img src={ImageIwant} alt="The image i want" width="80%" height="80%" />) : ''}
        <p>Here is the image</p>
      </div>);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you don't have a component to render if the prop value is false, I would use conditional rendering with the `&&` operator instead of an inline if statement.

```
const TheImage = { showImage } => (
  <div align="center">
    {showImage && <img src="https://lcsc.academyofmine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Test-Logo.svg.png" alt="The image i want" width="80%" height="80%" />}
    <p>Here is the image</p>
  </div>
);
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XwRpZR?editors=0010)